# how to check if value exists in table using cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**Edit - I fixed the original error, but now I still have one more**

When I click on "Upvote" I get the message "vote could not be saved" message meaning that for whatever reason, it's not querying properly (otherwise it would see that there is no record saved). Also, I get an error saying "Undefined index" but I'm not sure what it's referring to.

Here are my tables

```
Votes
id |  user_id | vote

Posts
id |  title | body | created | modified | user_id | vote_total
```

This is one of the links to upvote found on posts/index.ctp

```
<td><?php echo $this->Html->link('Upvote', array('action' => 'vote', $post['Post']['id']))?>
```

So, here's the vote function found in postscontroller.php

```
public function vote($id=null){

$this->Post->Votes->recursive = 0;

$this->Post->id = $id;
$user = $this->Auth->User();
$userid = $user['id'];
$conditions = array('votes.id' => $id, 'votes.user_id' => $userid, 'votes.vote' => '1');

$data = $this->Post->Votes->find('All' , array('conditions'=>$conditions));

if (isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
    echo '<p>User have already give a vote!</p>';
} else {

    if($this->Post->Votes->validates()){
        if ($this->Post->Votes->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The vote has been saved'));
        } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The vote could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }   
}
}
```

This relation is found in my Post.php model.

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Votes' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
        )
    );
```

This relation is found in User.php model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Posts' => array(
        'className'  => 'Post'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Add in your controller

```
<?php

public function vote($id=null){

    $this->layout = 'votes_layout';
    $this->Vote->recursive = 0;

    $user = $this->Auth->User();
    $userid = $user['id'];
    $conditions = array('Vote.post_id' => $id, 'Vote.user_id' => $userid);


    $data = $this->Vote->find('All' , arrar('conditions'=>$conditions));

    if (isset($data) && !empty($data) {
        echo '<p>User have already give a vote!</p>';
    } else {

        if($this->Vote->validates()){

            if ($this->Vote->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The vote has been saved'));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'vote'));
            } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The vote could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: you can get user_id for query string or session

Comment: I updated my code above. Can you please take a look at it, I'm still getting errors?

Comment: you have use votes i think your model name should be Vote  $this->Post->Votes and u used in Vote.id in condition it should be Vote.post_id and show me a your posts and votes db table strutcher

Comment: show me a your posts and votes db table stretcher and give me a model name

Comment: i have not seen the changes in your post

Comment: @user1406951 You need to post your updates to your original question, not by editing someone else's answer.

Comment: @saluce Wow, I'm sorry. I didn't realize I edited the wrong post!

Comment: @AbidHussain sorry, I edited the wrong post. I updated mine, please take a look again when you have a chance. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please let me know which class name you have to use in model file. Posts or Post And Votes or Vote

Comment: I updated my post above. I fixed my original problem, but now I'm having another one

Answer (score 1):

You may find this plugin helpful for your case:

https://github.com/CakeDC/ratings

It contains the logic for a voting (or rating) system that can be associated to any other model record in your app.